# Is $\nabla_{X}:\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$ continuous aplication?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Be $\Gamma(E)$ smooth sections space of an vector bundle, $\Gamma(E)$ with Fréchet topology. Gived a conexion in E and a smooth vector field $X$,  Is $\nabla_{X}: \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$ continuous aplication?

Comment: It doesn't go to $\Gamma(E)$...

Comment: ok... it depends of the  vector fields?

Comment: OK. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The answer is yes, to check this, just go through the definition, writing everything in local coordinates. If this sounds difficult, first do it in the case when $E$ is trivial bundle and $\nabla$ is the trivial connection.